# How to dynamically create multiple horizontal bar charts in Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, data-visualization

I'm new in Google Chart API.
I want to use it to visualize my data about the review on Google Play Store which include multiple issues, sentiments and other conditions.

I want to build a horizontal bar chart which x axis containing different app , and each app's containing 7 issues, y axis is the sum of sentiment of each issue in different app.

I have already done the horizontal chart containing all data in a single div element. However, for the user's convenience, I want to show 5 data at most in a single div element, and dynamically create div element if there is more than 5 data in the current data set. At last, the div elements which paint the chart will horizontally append to the another div element called **issueBar_div**. The user can use the scrollbar to view different chart.

### What I've done:

1. Partition data:

   ```
   var title = ['APP'];
   var issueRow = {{ projectissues|safe }}; // 7 different issues got from Django
   var graph_data = [title.concat(issueRow)];
   var cnt = 0;
   var divide_row = [];
   var tableRows = ... // tableRows is the app name mapping to sentiment sum which corresponding to different issue array dictionary.
   // like the form  APP -> [20, 12, -1, 3, 5, 21, 57]
   for (var app in tableRows) {
           cnt ++;                                
           var row = [app];
           for (var i = 0; i < tableRows[app].length; i++) {
               row.push(tableRows[app][i]);
           }
           if(cnt < 6){
               divide_row.push(row);
           }
           else{
               graph_data.push(divide_row);
               divide_row = [];
               cnt = 0;
           }
   }
   ```
2. Create the div element and draw the chart

In order to build a use the scrollbar, I add some restriction to the **issueBar_div**.

`<div id="issueBar_div" style="height:400px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden";></div>`

Dynamically create the div element  and draw.

```
    function drawIssueBar() {
        var issueBar = document.getElementById("issueBar_div");
        // titleRow include the APP and other issue
        var titleRow = graph_data[0];
        delete_element();
        for(var i = 1;i<graph_data.length;i++){
            // create div element and set their attribute
            var my_div = document.createElement("div");
            my_div.id = "issuebar_" + i;
            my_div.style.display = "table-cell";
            // append this element to #issueBar_div
            issueBar.appendChild(my_div);
            // get the sliced data and push to total_data
            var row_data = graph_data[i];
            var total_data = [titleRow];
            for(var k=0;k<row_data.length;k++){
                total_data.push(row_data[k]);
            }
            // the new data container
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(total_data);
            var div_width = $("#home").width();
            var materialOptions = {
                height: 400,
                width: div_width,
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'Sum of sentiment'
                },
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'APP'
                },
                bars: 'vertical'
            };
            var materialChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("issuebar_" + i));
            materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);
        } 
    }
    // delete the div element
    function delete_element(){
        i = 1;
        while(true){
            element = document.getElementById("issuebar_" + i);
            if(element !== null){
                element.outerHTML = "";
                delete element;
                i++;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

### Current Problem:

Basically, the created div elements will create as expect, but the chart will only show one chart as below.

[The successful chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r7q5.png)

[The fail part when move the scrollbar to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrwyI.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Any answer will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @WhiteHat, I have already tried it. It's a pity that the result remain the same.

Comment: No, there are just unrelated warning there.

Comment: what is the value of --> `graph_data[0]` -- does this return an array or single value?

Comment: it return a array, like the form of ["APP", "issue1", "issue2", "issue3"... "issue7"]. It will be the column name of each bar in bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

ALL. I have already solve my problem!!!

I notice that there is a very important sentence showing on Google Chart document:

***For each chart on the page, add a call to google.charts.setOnLoadCallback() with the callback that draws the chart as an input***

So I decide to callback drawing method when drawing each bar chart.

### The specific solution

1.I use the **new Function** as a callback function. The row_data is the data needing to present, and the my_div is the div element where to store the chart.

```
var drawIssueBar = new Function("row_data", "my_div",
        "var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(row_data);" +
        "var div_width = $('#home').width();" +
        "var materialOptions = {" + 
            "height: 400," + 
            "width: div_width," + 
            "hAxis: {" +
                "title: 'Sum of sentiment'" +
            "}," +
            "vAxis: {" +
                "title: 'APP'" +
            "}," +
            "bars: 'vertical'" +
        "};"+
        "var materialChart = new google.charts.Bar(my_div);" +
        "materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);"
    );
```

2.Rewrite the data processing.

```
    var titleRow = ... // like the form of ["APP", "issue1", "issue2", ..."issue7"]
    var cnt = 0;
    var divide_row = [];

    for (var app in tableRows) {
        cnt ++;                                
        var row = [app].concat(tableRows[app]);
        if(cnt < 6){
            divide_row.push(row);
        }
        else{
            graph_data.push([titleRow].concat(divide_row));
            // console.log(graph_data[graph_data.length - 1]);
            divide_row = [];
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }
```

3.Write a new function called **drawIssueChart** to draw all the bar chart.

```
    function drawIssueChart(){
        // create the div element and draw the chart
        delete_element();
        var issueBar = document.getElementById('issueBar_div');
        for(var i = 0;i<graph_data.length;i++){
            var my_div = document.createElement("div");
            my_div.id = "issuebar_" + i;
            my_div.style.display = "table-cell";
            issueBar.appendChild(my_div);
            var row_data = graph_data[i];
            // use the drawIssueBar as a callback
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawIssueBar(row_data, my_div));
        }
    }
```

### Result

[The successful chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqjU4.png)

[Another successful chart when moving the scrollbar to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56QLt.png)

I learn a lot from this solution!

Hopefully it can help the people who encounter this problem.

Comment: The Google Chart document reference: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts